# Is the integral operator bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following problem.

Suppose $\mu$ - measure on $T$, $K(s,t) \geq 0$ and measurable function on $T \times T$ with respect to $\mu \times \mu$. U is the integral operator:
$$(Uf)(s) = \int\limits_T K(s,t)f(t) dt.$$
I know that $Uf \in L^2(\mu)$ if $f \in L^\infty(\mu)$ and the following estimate:
$$\int\limits_T K(s,t) K(s,x) ds \leq C (K(t,x) + K(x,t)),$$
where $C>0$. I want to prove that $U$ is bounded operator from $L^2(\mu)$ to itself.

I observe that
\begin{align}
(Uf, Uf) &= \int\limits_T \left( \int\limits_T K(s, t) f(t) dt \int\limits_T K(s, \tau) f(\tau) d\tau\right) ds\\
& = \int\limits_T \int\limits_T \int\limits_T K(s, t) K(s, \tau)ds f(\tau) f(t) dt d\tau \\
& \leq \int\limits_T \int\limits_T f(\tau) f(t) C(K(t, \tau) + K(\tau, t)) dt d\tau \\
&\leq 2C(Uf, f)
\end{align}
for every $f \geq 0$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ means inner product in $L^2(\mu)$.
But I don't is it useful.

Comment: I didn't check your work, but since you conclude with $(Uf,Uf) \le 2C(Uf,f)$ you should apply Cauchy-Schwarz to find that $\|Uf\|^2 \le 2C \|f\|\|Uf\|$. Now divide by $\|Uf\|$.

Comment: You shall also define $T$.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know that $||Uf|| < \infty$, so I can't divide by it, that is why Cauchy-Schwarz can't help.

Comment: In the original formulation of the problem, T is an abstract set with measure

Comment: @Timal: At least if $f \in L^\infty$, you know by assumption that $U f\in L^2$. So first Show boundedness on $L^\infty \cap L^2$ and then generalize to all of $L^2$ a posteriori.

Comment: @PhoemueX That is the problem: I don't understand how to generalize. So if you have an idea how to solve it could you please explain?

Comment: @PhoemueX Generally speaking this is the obstacle I can't get around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your estimate as
$$
\|Uf\|_2^2\leq 2C\,(Uf,f)\leq2C\,\|Uf\|_2\,\|f\|.
$$
So for any $f\in L^\infty$, you get $\|Uf\|_2\leq 2C\,\|f\|_2$.

Fix $f\in L^2$. Assume first that $f\geq0$. Choose $\{f_j\}\subset L^\infty\cap L^2$ with $f_j\nearrow f$ (for instance we can take the $f_j$ to be simple functions). Then, by Monotone Convergence (since $K\geq0$), $Uf_j\nearrow Uf$. Using Monotone Convergence again and that $Uf\geq0$, $Uf_j\geq0$,
$$
\|Uf\|_2^2=\lim_j\|Uf_j\|_2^2\leq4C^2\,\limsup_j\|f_j\|_2^2\leq4C^2\,\|f\|_2^2. 
$$
So $Uf\in L^2$, and $\|Uf\|_2\leq 2C\\|f\|_2$ when $f\geq0$.

For arbitrary $f\in L^2$, we can write $f=f_1-f_2+i(f_3-f_4)$ with $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\geq0$, $f_1f_2=0$, $f_3f_4=0$. Then
\begin{align}
\|Uf\|_2&\leq\|Uf_1\|_2+\|Uf_2\|_2+\|Uf_3\|_2+\|Uf_4\|_2\\[0.3cm]
&\leq 8C\,\max\big\{\|f_1\|_2,\|f_2\|_2,\|f_3\|_2,\|f_4\|_2\big\}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq 8C\,\|f\|_2. 
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, but why is $\widetilde U$ equal to the U. You proved, that U can be extended from $L^2 \cap L^\infty$ to all space as bounded. But I need to prove that U is already bounded in $L^2$. $U$ is the integral operator, but why $\widetilde U$ is the integral and equals to the $U$ is nontrivial.

Comment: I have changed the answer a bit.